# Apache Solr handle hundreds of thousands requests

Tags: java, solr, lucene, performance-testing, solrcloud

We have a small search app in local context. For back services, we are using Apache Solr 6.6.2 for data index and storage. The front-end is in PHP with Apache2 webserver.

We have a server of 48 core and 96 GB RAM where these services are installed. The expected size of documents in index in about 200 Million and each document can have maximum 20 fields. Most fields are both indexed and stored.

The expected simultaneous requests can be hundreds of thousands at a time. So what will be the best configuration of Apache Solr to handle it? We have started Solr with 20 GB RAM and stress tested but it start to degrade performance near 100 users. Where is the problem? What is the optimal way for this issue.

We have also tested Solr in SolrCloud mode but the performance does not improve too much. We were expecting that if there will be some memory problem that their will be OOM exception but did not happen anything like that. We have just changed schema according to our requirement and change memory via command-line. All other setting are default.

Following are few references that we have consulted already

1. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems
2. https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/06/apache-solr-memory-tuning-for-production/

Comment: If you're trying to handle over 100k simultaneous connections, you probably want to hand over connection termination to a dedicated load balancer and put a cluster of nodes behind that - trying to make a single node handle such a load over HTTP _simultaeous_ will be a difficult task without detailed domain knowledge.

Comment: Currently about 60 GB memory of the server is free. Then why I should use a load balancer at frond and put a cluster of nodes behind it. Can single solr instance with such large memory and core cannot handle it ? If it is true , then can you provide some references to consult ?

Comment: 100k simultaneous connections are far into the area of special tuning for most http daemons. Using the built-in version of jetty _without tuning it_ might not be a good fit for your use case. Memory is not the only thing limiting how many connections or queries a server can handle. Getting a specialized httpd such as nginx to handle more than 3-4k simultaneous connections usually require tuning for special use cases and trading certain features for performance. Are you _really sure_ that you need 100k simultaneous connections (and what I guess is 100k queries in parallel)?

Comment: 100k queries would first kill CPU, doesn’t matter how many free RAM you have

Comment: Thanks first. Brother there are 48 CPU cores. Is it possible to tune Solr (jetty) to use some of these cores to handle such load. Moreover, if I have to tune Solr then can you please share some guide or tutorial for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**We have 200 million records in each Collection and we have 200 collections. We have 5 servers and each server has 8 cores and 64 gb ram.**

**I would suggest you break up your servers into multiple servers**.

**Do the replication of the data on each server so that requests gets divided into multiple servers. The more the number of servers, the more you'll be able to responsd quicker.**

**Note :** *Just understand the replication factor : 2F+1 formula where if you have 5 servers then 3 replicas atleast should be there. I'll suggest you to go with 5 replicas only (1 replica for each server)*

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to handle hundreds of thousands of requests per second you will need more than one server - no matter how big it is. Even if it's just for HA / DR purposes. So I would recommend using SolrCloud and sharding the index across multiple machines and with multiple replicas just so start.

Beyond that the devil is in the details

1. How fast do you want queries to perform (median and 99%ile). This will help you size CPU and memory needs.
2. How complex are your queries?
3. Are you using filters? (Requires more heap memory)
4. How fast is your disk acccess?
5. Will you be adding data in real time (impacting your setting of autoCommit and soft commit

But first and foremost you need to get away from "one big box" thinking.

Comment: Brother thanks for guide. In our case, document addition is not in real time, there are 5-10 filters in each query, the storage is local file system (the disk) and we want queries performance near 99%ile. also, Can you suggest some reference guide for this purpose ?

Comment: Sadly no - it's so data specific - everytime anyone asks on the Solr Lucene platform mailing list the answer is always the same so I doubt I can add more. So my suggestion is baseline your performance with a given "best guess" architecture and then analyze your requests - are they all largely the same (in that case you'll need more memory for caching of query results), what's the peak request rate - can Jetty handle that many parallel requests? etc.  Solr/Lucene can rely on CPU/Memory/Network/Disk IO in so many different ways that it's really environment specific. Sorry!